# Github, pull request, files changed. Is there any way to ignore certain files in this view?

Tags: github

I have a Unity3d project on github, which consists of C# files and also not really human readable .unity and .prefab files. I'm wondering is there a way when reviewing a pull request, when looking at the  'files changed' tab to see only the c# files that have been changed?
Otherwise you have to wade through all the non human readable stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as 'textual', changing the 'Asset Serialization' option on Editor Settings. 
From Unity's website:

"
Textual Scene File Format

As well as the default binary format, Unity also provides a textual format for scene data. This can be useful when working with version control software, since textual files generated separately can be merged more easily than binary files...
"

Source:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextualSceneFormat.html

Cheers!